# Exercise 6 from Chapter 11 Programming in C Kochan, finding bit patterns

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit

hoping for some help with bitwise operators. The exercise reads as following:

> Write a function called bitpat_search() that looks for the occurence of a specified pattern of bits inside an unsigned int. The function should take three arguments, and should be called as such:
>
> ```
>    bitpat_search (source, pattern, n)
> ```
>
> The function searches for the integer "source", starting at the leftmost bit, to see if the rightmost n bits of "pattern" occur in "source". If the pattern is found, have the function return the number of the bit at which the pattern begins, where the leftmost bit is number 0. If the pattern is not found, then have the function return -1. So, for example, the call
>
> ```
>    index = bitpat_search (0xe1f4, 0x5, 3);
> ```
>
> causes the bit_pat(search() function to search the number 0xe1f4 (= 1110 0001 1111 0100 binary) for the occurence of the three-bit pattern 0x5 (= 101 binary). The function returns 11 to indicate that the pattern was found in the "source" beginning with bit number 11.
>
> Make certain that the function makes no assumptions about the size of an int.

I've got a few problems getting this working:

1- The numbers don't actually make much sense to me... I've tried all kinds of printf() functions after each itiration, and it looks like the 0x5 number gets read as 100 binary, which would be four. If I try other numbers they just come fairly random, but often as 000, so.... not very helpful. Am I counting them wrong? Does the right shift change it somehow?

2 - it's returning the wrong position (19 rather than 11), but while I'm messing up the numbers as my q1 above, it's not really going to work, is it?

Sorry if this is obvious to all you lovely people, I just can see it. (I'm just trying to learn from the book btw, it's not homework from school).

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

int int_size(unsigned int num);
int bit_test(unsigned int word, int position, int size);
int bitpat_search(unsigned int source, unsigned int pattern, int n);

int main(void)
{
    int index;

    index  = bitpat_search(0xe1f4, 0x5, 3);

    printf(" Pattern found in position %i\n", index);
    return 0;
}

int bitpat_search(unsigned int source, unsigned int pattern, int n)
{
    int i, j, tempSource, tempPat, count;

    int size = int_size(~0);

    for (i = 0; i < size;)
    {
        count = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            tempSource = bit_test(source, i, size);
            tempPat = bit_test(pattern, j, size);

            i++;
            count++;

            if (tempSource != tempPat)
            break;
        }
        if (count == n)
            return i - n;
    }
    return 0;

}

int bit_test(unsigned int word, int position, int size)
{
    if( (word >> (size - position)) & 0x1) // shift bits in word 31 minus n     spaces right, and AND word with hexadecimal 1
        return 1; // if above is true (1 & 1) return 1
    else
        return 0;

}

int int_size(unsigned int num)
{
    int size = 0;

    while (num)
    {
        size++;
        num >>= 1;
    }

    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < size;)
{
    count = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        tempSource = bit_test(source, i, size);
        tempPat = bit_test(pattern, j, size);
```

Here, you're checking a bit at position `i` in the source against a bit at position `j` in the pattern. That needs to be `i+j` in the source, otherwise you compare a pattern against one bit, rather than a pattern against a *number* of bits, in the source. Since the pattern 101 contains ones and a zero, you'll never find anything.

Side note: you can replace the `int_size` function by `sizeof(int)*8`. That assumes 8-bit bytes, but computers for which that assumption does not hold haven't been made since the early eighties, so that should be a fairly safe assumption.

Comment: `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT` would not assume 8-bit bytes, but it *still* assumes that `int` doesn't have padding-bits, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: In the request, the size doesn't assume to a `sizeof(int)` but **"starting at the leftmost bit"**. And in the case of the source value to be checked `0xe1f4`, the size is 16bits `1110 0001 1111 0100`. So, `int size = int_size(source);`.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- The numbers don't actually make much sense to me... I've tried all kinds of printf() functions after each itiration, and it looks like the 0x5 number gets read as 100 binary, which would be four. If I try other numbers they just come fairly random, but often as 000, so.... not very helpful. Am I counting them wrong?

I can't comment on code you've not presented, but of course hex `0x5` is binary `101`.  I'm inclined to suppose that in your tests you printed different values than you thought you were printing, or that your mechanism for printing them was flawed.

> Does the right shift change it somehow?

Shift operators leave their operands unchanged.  Of course, if the right-hand operand of a conforming shift operation is non-zero then the *result* differs from the left-hand operand.  If the left-hand operand is drawn from a variable, then you might conceivably overwrite that variable's value afterward.

> 2 - it's returning the wrong position (19 rather than 11), but while I'm messing up the numbers as my q1 above, it's not really going to work, is it?

I don't think your main problem is "messing up the numbers".  Your implementation is problematic.  Consider the key loop nest in your code:

```
for (i = 0; i < size;)
{
    count = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        tempSource = bit_test(source, i, size);
        tempPat = bit_test(pattern, j, size);

        i++;
        count++;
```

Observe that you increment the outer loop's control variable on each iteration of the inner loop.  As a result, you test the pattern only against every `n`<sup>th</sup> starting index in the source string.  That is, you test non-overlapping sets of the source bits.  You should instead test the whole pattern starting at every possible starting position.

Note also that you test starting positions where an `n-bit` pattern cannot possibly start, on account of there being fewer than `n` bits between that position and the end of the source string.  In this case you will end up invoking undefined behavior by using an invalid right-hand operand to a shift operator.

Comment: As an aside, I'd not perform the test on a bit-by-bit basis in the first place.  You could replace the substantially the whole inner loop with a right shift (`>>`), a bitwise and (`&`), and a bitwise exclusive or (`^`), thereby testing all the pattern bits at once.

Comment: Thanks John, I'll try again... And your second suggestion of using bitwise operators is probably what I'm meant to do, if I can just figure out how to. I do wish the book came with answers, not because I want to copy and paste (I hate that), but sometimes, when I'm truly stuck, it would be nice to get some idea of what I'm meant to have understood. I generally try not to move on until I understand both the question and answer anyway (which is lucky, as the very first time I ran this program it actually produced the right answer, but it was based on a mistake, so just a fluke).

Answer (score 0):

In the proposed algorithm, except the revealed issue by @WouterVerhelst, it exists other issues causing a wrong result.

**Issue 1** - In the function `bit_test()`, the tested-bit is not the expected one.

> To test a bit from the leftmost side, replace `(size - position)` by
>   `(size - (position + 1))`.

```
int bit_test(unsigned int word, int position, int size)
{
    if( (word >> (size - (position + 1))) & 0x1) // 
        return 1; // if above is true (1 & 1) return 1
    else
        return 0;
}
```

**Issue 2** - To be tested as the same size of `source`, the `pattern` shall be aligned to left.

> In the `bitpat_search()`, before for-loop, shift-left of `(size-n)`
>   bits.

```
int size = int_size(source);

pattern = pattern << (size-n);
```

**Issue 3** - To have the correct `count` to be compared with `n`, the comparison of bits with the `break;` should be done before `count++`.

```
    if (tempSource != tempPat)
        break;

    count++;
```

**Issue 4** - The index result returned would be `i` instead of `i - n` (linked with Issue 5).

```
if (count == n)
    return (i); // instead of (i - n);
```

**Issue 5** - As @WouterVerhelst suggests, the comparison between `source` and `pattern` should be done for each bit.

```
for (i = 0; i < size;i++) // each bit ==> i++
{
    count = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        tempSource = bit_test(source, i+j, size);
        tempPat = bit_test(pattern, j, size);
        // not here i++;

        if (tempSource != tempPat)
            break;

        count++;
    }
    if (count == n)
        return (i);
}
```

**Issue 6** - And the result in case of 'pattern not found' is -1.

```
return (-1); // Instead of (0);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now! Now I just have to write it out on paper and understand why..... thank you! (And then I should probably try John's suggestion with using bitwise operators, but babysteps seems necessary first).